# concatenate dataframe with overlapping keys non overlapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a number of client rating flat files, one per business unit/division and it contains the rating for that specific client in that business unit. Some clients can cross multiple business units so could have one rating in one unit and a different rating in a different file or none at all.

I want a single data structure where I can look up a particular client and get all applicable ratings for that client.

**example data**

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'client': ['Client_A', 'Client_B', 'Client_C'], 'bank_rating': ['A', 'A', 'B']})
df1.set_index('client', inplace=True)

df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'client': ['Client_A', 'Client_C'], 'insurance_rating': ['B', 'A']})
df2.set_index('client', inplace=True)

df3 = pandas.DataFrame({'client': ['Client_B', 'Client_D'], 'wealth_rating': ['D', 'A']})
df3.set_index('client', inplace=True)

frames = [df1, df2, df3] #in reality frames is a dynamic list built from x number of files in a folder
```

**attempted solution**

```
df = pandas.concat(frames)

          bank_rating  insurance_rating  wealth_rating
client
Client_A  A            NaN               NaN
Client_B  A            NaN               NaN
Client_C  B            NaN               NaN
Client_A  NaN          B                 NaN
Client_C  NaN          A                 NaN
Client_B  NaN          NaN               D
Client_D  NaN          NaN               A
```

**what i want** is a unique row per customer with each business unit rating as column

```
          bank_rating  insurance_rating  wealth_rating
client    
Client_A  A            B                 NaN
Client_B  A            NaN               D
Client_C  B            A                 NaN
Client_D  NaN          NaN               A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, it's just that concat assumes that you want to add new rows to the dataframes (the 0'th axis). So writing

```
df = pandas.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: that was the parameter I initially tried changing. Using my example I'm getting the result I want. Now can't remember what was wrong with this on my real dataset :/

Comment: Yes, this works on the example you gave here. So are you saying that you have a larger dataset where this approach does not work?

Comment: got it! My real dataset had a number of extra columns, with extra client data (address, phone # etc). So I set a multi-index as my common columns as they should be identical for each client. The reason why it didn't work as expected is because there was some whitespace characters as padding in some of these fields. I ended up dropping these columns and just using the client_id column to ```concat``` against.